# What are some quirks of the Java compiler?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compilation, compiler-errors, javac

IntelliJ has an inspection setting to warn you of "Javac quirks" that might affect your code, but I have yet to come across any. What are some of these quirks, either recognized by IntelliJ or in general?

Comment: This may help you: http://tavianator.com/2013/07/java-generics-quirks/

Comment: I have yet to come across any 'quirks' too, but then I've only been using it for 17.5 years.

Comment: There [seems to be](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.jetbrains/intellij-idea/13.0.0/com/intellij/codeInspection/compiler/JavacQuirksInspectionVisitor.java?av=f) 2 "quirks" detected by IntelliJ, one dealing with trailing commas for an array initializer in an annotation - the other one I can't figure out. A textual description can probably be found by anyone digging up the properties file used for e.g. the "inspection.compiler.javac.quirks.anno.array.comma.problem" property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've just seen "Use of '_' as a lambda parameter name is not allowed" (IntelliJ IDEA CE 14.0.2).

```
public static <T> BinaryOperator<T> toLastElement() {
    return (_, current) -> current;
}
```